# Combine two 2x2 designs in one 2x2x2: pro and cons?

Tags: experiment-design

we investigated whether and how food deprivation (i.e. energetic state) affects behavioral responses of  tadpoles to predation risk. We combined a food regime (fed vs. fasted tadpoles) with a predatory cue treatment (risk vs. no risk) and assessed the effect of their interaction on tadpoles’ level of activity. 
results were unexpected and we hypothesized that they may depended on the absence of food in test containers.
Thus we did a second exp, identical to the first but adding food in the containers: results supported our hypothesis.
While trying to publish, a referee suggested to combine the two 2x2 exp in one 2x2x2 (fed-fasted, risk-no risk, food-no food).

I feel that it would be wrong to combine as exp were carried out in succession, but I would like to have a "stronger" statement of reasons (if any)

Comment: There are probably arguments both ways here. Can you specify why you think conditions may have changed between the two runs of the experiment in a way which satisfied the referee.

Comment: Your attention to the sequential character of your inferences here brings to mind the 'Strong Inference' famously discussed by Platt in his [1964 *Science* essay](http://knowledgecontext.org/COSMOS/Strong_Inference_(Platt).pdf).

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you can't combine both experiments into a 2 × 2 × 2 analysis. The catch is that one of those independent variables (IVs) is not like the others. I presume that in both experiments the food regime and predatory cue IVs were randomly assigned per tadpole (since you call them "experiments"), in which case you know that these IVs aren't confounded with anything else. On the other hand, container status wasn't randomly assigned, and is confounded with, among other things, the order in which you ran tadpoles. Hence you can't be sure that the effect of container observed in your analysis is really the causal effect of container and not something else, or something on top of the causal effect of container.

In short, you can do the analysis so long as you interpret it keeping in mind that one of the IVs isn't randomly assigned and is totally confounded with study.

Comment: I'd advise abandoning 'IV' as abbreviation for *independent variable*, since in a discussion of *causality*, this acronym invariably refers to [instrumental variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variables_estimation).

Comment: @DavidC.Norris How should it be abbreviated?

Comment: In [design of experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_experiments) discussions, such variables that are **manipulated experimentally** are typically called *treatments*. You might do best to use that term, since 'independent variables' (and indeed 'instrumental variables' as well!) is a more generic notion that also encompasses *natural variation* that is not experimentally manipulated.

Comment: @DavidC.Norris But by "IV" here I indeed mean any variables that are used as input variables to the model, i.e., covariates or features, whether they were manipulated or not.

Comment: Ah, I see that now, yes. In that case, you could refer to 'treatment assignments' and '[observed] covariates' separately, rather than lumping all as 'independent variables'. Carrying over this distinction into your choice of terminology might improve your exposition.